# Oracle Sql to check online performance based on log in and log out

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that logs record of a device's log in and log out. Log in would mean that the device is working at that time and log out would mean that the device is down.

DEVICE_LOG table

[image: DEVICE_LOG]

I want to create a query that would check how long the Device is working for a certain period (i.e from 09/15/2013 00:00:00 to 09/16/2013 00:00:00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use LAG function, for example:

```
select *, (record_date - LAG(record_date, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY dev_id ORDER BY record_date)) *24*60 min
from device_log
```

use your partition by what you need

Comment: Lead and lag function solved this problem. Thanks mr.dump. 

Now I have another question. I would like to check how much time the device is online from 2:00PM to 4:00PM of dates 09/15/2013 to 09/16/2013? Is this possible through sql only? Or do I need to create a procedure? 

Should I create another thread or can I insert it here?

Comment: @JohnGo if I correctly understand you John You need the period of work. That's it: select (to_date('09/16/2013 4:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM') - to_date('09/15/2013 2:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM'))*24 PeriodInHour
       , (to_date('09/16/2013 4:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM') - to_date('09/15/2013 2:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM'))*24*60 PeriodInMin
       , (to_date('09/16/2013 4:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM') - to_date('09/15/2013 2:00PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miPM'))*24*60*60 PeriodInSec
from dual

Comment: @JohnGo As you see it's possible through sql and it's so simple)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain. I already have the following query below:
SELECT d.*,
       (   Lead(record_date, 1, '09/16/2013 00:00:00')
over (
PARTITION BY dev_id
ORDER BY record_date) -  record_date) * 24 * 60 min_lead,
       ( record_date - Lag(record_date, 1, '09/15/2013 12:00:00')
over ( PARTITION BY dev_id
ORDER BY record_date) ) * 24 * 60 min_LAG
FROM   device_log d
WHERE  dev_id = 'DEVICE001'
and record_date between '09/15/2013 12:00:00' and '09/16/2013 00:00:00'

Comment: The query will ge me the following ( i have removed other details from the query)
DEV_ID  STATUS MIN_LEAD MIN_LAG
DEVICE001 000 180  322.1666667
DEVICE001 001 217.8333333 180
Basically from 09/15/2013 12:00:00 to 09/16/2013 00:00:00
the device has a status of 001 for 217.8333333 + 322.1666667 mins
and 000 status of 180 mins.

Is there a way to make a query to sum all the mins with 001 status and 000 status?